# Create unit test for file creation with content

Tags: unit-testing, go

I've the following function which getting a file and write content to it.

```
func setFile(file *os.File, appStr models.App) {

    file.WriteString("1.0")

    file.WriteString("Created-By: application generation process")
    for _, mod := range appStr.Modules {

        file.WriteString(NEW_LINE)
        file.WriteString(NEW_LINE)
        file.WriteString("Application")
        file.WriteString(NEW_LINE)
        file.WriteString("ApplicationContent")
        file.WriteString(NEW_LINE)
        file.WriteString("ContentType")

    }
}
```

For that I generate a unit test like following

```
func Test_setFile(t *testing.T) {


    type args struct {
        file   *os.File
        appStr models.App
    }
    var tests []struct {
        name string
        args args
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            setFile(tt.args.file, tt.args.AppStr)
        })
    }
}
```

The problem here is that **im depending on file**, what is better approach to create unit test for this kind of function

1. run code in the unit test which is creating file update it with this function and then parse it and check the values ? is there a better approach for this kind of function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better approach would be to accept an interface, something like `io.Writer`. In your real usage you can pass in a `*os.File`, and in your tests you can pass in something easier to work with like a `bytes.Buffer`.

Something like (untested but should get you started):

```
func setFile(file io.Writer, appStr models.App) {
    fmt.Fprint(file, "1.0")

    fmt.Fprint(file, "Created-By: application generation process")
    for _, mod := range appStr.Modules {
        fmt.Fprint(file, NEW_LINE)
        fmt.Fprint(file, NEW_LINE)
        fmt.Fprint(file, "Application")
        fmt.Fprint(file, NEW_LINE)
        fmt.Fprint(file, "ApplicationContent")
        fmt.Fprint(file, NEW_LINE)
        fmt.Fprint(file, "ContentType")
    }
}

func Test_setFile(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        appStr models.App
    }
    var tests []struct {
        name string
        args args
        expected []byte
   }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            b := &bytes.Buffer{}
            setFile(b, tt.args.AppStr)
            if !bytes.Equal(b.Bytes(), tt.expected) {
                t.Error("somewhat bad happen")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! , since im not sure how to do it can you please provide some sample code ?

Comment: Updated with a sample.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , for example how should I check that it prints "ApplicationContent"?

Comment: Put whatever you expect it to print in the `expected` field of the test, or if you want to check partial content, update the test accordingly. The sample code is meant as just that, a sample - it should be enough for you to write your own tests using it as a base.

Comment: I see, the `only` thing that I miss here for my example is how should I create the ` var tests []struct {
  name     string
  args     args
  expected []byte
 }` what should I put in args? it will be great if you can update your answer.

Comment: It's unchanged from your original code, so I assumed you wrote it and knew how it worked. If you don't understand how to use table driven tests, do a Google search (it's a very common practice) and if it still doesn't make sense, post a new question about that.

Comment: as you suggest i've opend new question, please have a look if you can help , thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600193/go-table-driven-test-for-file-creation