# Table-driven test for file creation

Tags: unit-testing, go

I got an example from @volker about table driven test like following
But currently I miss what I should put in the real test, this test is using byte, currently im not sure what to put in the `args` and the `expected []byte`, 
e.g. I want to check that in the file there is `2 new line` and then `application` entry, how can I do it without the need to create the real file and parse it?

```
type Models struct {
    name        string
    vtype       string
    contentType string
}

func setFile(file io.Writer, appStr Models) {
    fmt.Fprint(file, "1.0")

    fmt.Fprint(file, "Created-By: application generation process")
    for _, mod := range appStr.Modules {
        fmt.Fprint(file, "\n")
        fmt.Fprint(file, "\n")
        fmt.Fprint(file,  appStr.vtype) //"userApp"
        fmt.Fprint(file, "\n")
        fmt.Fprint(file, appStr.name) //"applicationValue"
        fmt.Fprint(file, "\n")
        fmt.Fprint(file, appStr.contentType)//"ContentType"
    }
}

func Test_setFile(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        appStr models.App
    }
    var tests []struct {
        name string
        args args
        expected []byte
   }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            b := &bytes.Buffer{}
            setFile(b, tt.args.AppStr)
            if !bytes.Equal(b.Bytes(), tt.expected) {
                t.Error("somewhat bad happen")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I read and understand the following example but not for byte and file
https://medium.com/@virup/how-to-write-concise-tests-table-driven-tests-ed672c502ae4

Comment: If you're only checking for the content that won't change based on the input, then you really only need one test. Your expected would be `[]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s", NEW_LINE, NEW_LINE, "Application"))`.

Comment: @Gavin - Thanks, can you please provide it as answer  ?

Comment: @Gavin - do you mean something like ` var tests []struct {
  name     string
  args     args
  expected []byte
 }
 {
  []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s", NEW_LINE, NEW_LINE, "Application"))
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only checking for the static content at the beginning, then you really only need one test. It would look something like this:

```
func Test_setFile(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        appStr models.App
    }
    var tests []struct {
        name string
        args args
        expected []byte
    }{
        name: 'Test Static Content',
        args: args{appStr: 'Some String'},
        expected: []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s", NEW_LINE, NEW_LINE, "Application")),
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            b := &bytes.Buffer{}
            setFile(b, tt.args.AppStr)
            if !bytes.Equal(b.Bytes(), tt.expected) {
                t.Error("somewhat bad happen")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Although, since you only have one case for this test, there really isn't a need to use table driven tests here. You could clean it up to look something like this:

```
func Test_setFile(t *testing.T) {
    b := &bytes.Buffer{}
    setFile(b, 'Some String')
    want := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s", NEW_LINE, NEW_LINE, "Application"))
    got := b.Bytes()
    if !bytes.Equal(want, got) {
        t.Errorf("want: %s got: %s", want, got)
    }
}
```